# I'm looking for the spelling of the word which is pronounced [cashay]

Tags: orthography

I'm looking for the spelling of the word which is pronounced [cashay] and means "a desired status". eg. "being knowledgeable in popular TV shows has a certain [cashay] among teenagers today."

Comment: Search cashay ... and voila!

Comment: Googling 'cashay' + 'meaning' redirects you to the correct word.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [***cachet***](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cachet) [TFD]:

> **cachet**
>   1 a. Great prestige or appeal: *a designer label with cachet*.
>   b. A quality of prestige or appeal: *"Federal courts have a certain cachet which state courts lack" (Christian Science Monitor).*
>   c. A mark, as of distinction, individuality, or authenticity: *"In our times the thick wad of credit cards is a cachet of respectability" (John D. MacDonald).*

Comment: On a site aimed at linguists?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't see you trying to send this to ELL.

Comment: I close-voted 38 minutes ago on 'lack of reasonable research' grounds. LMGTFY. As, I assume, did lbf. I'd have thought the people on ELL would expect some research too.  // Though I'd often find multiple close-votes useful.

Comment: There were no close votes when I replied to your tart little comment. But hey, my bad for feeling generous today. I should have known that would rub this site the wrong way.

Comment: You may not have been able to _see_ any. Let's get it right. // But hey, who cares about trying to maintain standards?

Comment: Standards? What is this, the IEEE? No, this is the site with [tag:single-word-request] questions.